# Android application working in selected devices

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

AndroidManifest.xml

`

```
<permission
    android:name="com.javapapers.android.googleplacesdetail.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.javapapers.android.googleplacesdetail.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AddressGenerator"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIza****ZMt6AZZ0qJhvct-OXni8mXRXgw*****" />
</application>
```

`

I have developed a map based application to find nearby places like atm, banks, hospitals, malls, etc. Its working perfectly in my device (HTC Desiire 816, Android 4.4.2). But when I check on another device (tested in Lenovo) of same Android version, it doesnt work, just the world map (with default lat, long position) loads and rest other component dont work. Both devices have the same Android Version. Kitkat 4.4.2. It doesnt work in Lollipop either. Its just that it works on couple of devices and doesnt work in others. 
What can be the possible issue? And the suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on Location mode. Location mode should be High accuracy.
I think your device by default taking Device only mode so these problem you are facing.

Comment: In whichever device I have tested, all have Location enabled on a high accuracy mode.